How do I safely move aquatic snails?
I am moving soon and need to take my snails with me.
How can I safely move them? Do I put them in a Ziploc with air? Should I just remove some water and pickup their whole tank?

You need to be careful with several details.
At the destination, you must have a receiving, cycled, environment for them (aquarium). If not, you have two alternatives: take some water from the current aquarium (and some dirt from the filter, as much as possible), so you can start easily; or take the entire aquarium (how? please ask another question).
It is also important how much time you will be on the road, and how will you travel. 20 min of walking and 2 days by train are not the same thing.
Ensure the right temperature. Is the temperature of the environment is not suitable, the snails will either be stressed (and possibly get sick), or downright die. If you expect the temperature to be outside of suitable range, you will need to find a solution.
Ensure mechanical safety. Unlike fish (made mostly of muscles), the snails have fragile shells. If the shells break, things will not be very good for them. So depending on the details, you need to make sure they arrive each in one piece. One way to ensure this safety is to put each snail in it own bag with water and air - which will act as a cushion between them.
Depending on the number of snails, and their size, the task might be quite tedious, but if they are important to you, we wish you luck.

Do I put them in a Ziploc with air?

I would not trust these things to remain zipped or locked during the transportation. Use a longer bag, made from some solid material, so you can make a knot at the mouth of the bag - securing the environment inside. Be careful that the thin bags for vegetables available for free at supermarkets are not at all strong. They could be suitable for a quick and easy transportation (where you can monitor the snails for the entire duration), but not for something more complicated.

Alternative
Donate the current snails to someone in the original area, and buy new snails at the destination. A lot less trouble.

NOTE: This answer applies to moving any aquatic beings - with variations specific of each being.
